# How to access sqlite db file in vscode plugin code?

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-plugin

How to access sqlite db file in vscode plugin code?
I am trying to build a plugin when i have a requirement of reading the sqlite db file from local file system.

tried using SQL.js and sqlite3. Is there any way i can read the buffer and convert it into JSON?